# Margin from edge

Tags: php, css, margin

Little issue with margin, code is bellow:

```
        echo '<p class="news_post">';
        $stripped = strip_tags($post,'<img>');
        $break = str_replace('>','><br>',$stripped);

        echo $results['post'];

        echo '</span></span>';
        $fetchtags = $results['tags'];
        $string = array ( '/\b(.*?)\b/i' );
        $replace = array ( '<a href="?inav=tag&amp;tag=$1">$1</a>' );
        $tags = preg_replace($string, $replace, $fetchtags);
        echo '<p>Tags: '.$tags.'</p>';
```

Want to try margin post from edge 10px? and also tags

`style.cs`s looks like this:

```
p.news_container {
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:verdana;
    color:white;
    margin-left: 10px;
    }

p.news_post {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family:verdana;
    color: #8A8A8A;
    margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

Some how my code doesn't work, tried everything. I think I messed up somewhere.

Comment: Please post your html code?

Comment: What have you added, your html? and where?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your html and my wild guess is that `margin-left: 10px;` isn't working for you so try changing that to:

```
position: relative;
left: 10px;
```

I'm pretty sure that should work.